# Static property memory consumption in running C# application

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

**Query 1:**

I have a web app with an xml file of 100 lines approximately; When my web app is running, I need to write values in that xml file(twice) and read values from that application many times; Once all values are updated in xml file, I tried to read the values in 2 ways,

1. I will de-serialize the xml file and store all the values in a static object and use it in my web app;
2. Each time when I need data, I will parse exactly to the respective xml element and get the value;

My doubts:

- If I go with first approach, is holding values in a static object, a wrong approach which may cause memory consumption?
- If I follow second approach, I frequently parse xml file; Is this right instead?

Please tell which is the correct approach for my use case;

Comment: Side note: caching is hard, and using `static` variables is generally worst option to implement caching , especially in ASP.Net.

Comment: Please don't ask 2 unrelated questions in one post. Second set should definitely be duplicate of existing question - make sure to search before asking separate question...

Answer (score 1):

Query 1: You should go with the first option you mentioned because it is really expensive to go each time to the xml file and get the specific data.

**But** you don't need to put in into a static object, you can deserialize it into some local variable you pass through the functions or use a global variable (try to avoid using globals).